# Mapping a server object to another object

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a server response in this format:

```
"BudgetDays": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Date": "2019-01-08T00:00:00",
            "Earned": 10,
            "Spent": 8,
            "Logged": false,
            "LoggedTime": "2019-02-10T12:36:09.377"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Date": "2019-01-09T00:00:00",
            "Earned": 23,
            "Spent": 30,
            "Logged": false,
            "LoggedTime": "2019-02-10T12:36:09.38"
        }, ...
```

The Typescript class is lowercase/camelcase, how can I map the json to the camelcase?

The function returns `BudgetDate[]` so I need to map it to that somehow:

```
return this.http.get<Budget>(this.apiRoot + '/api/budgetdays', { params: params })
  .pipe(
    map(budgetDatesList.BudgetDates => sameObjectWithCamelCase),
    catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error))
  );
```

How can I map the object to have lowercase properties.

Answer (score 0):

The RxJS side of the solution is simple—just use the `map` operator as you've already identified.

The trickier part is transforming all property keys in the response data object received.

Assuming that all keys in your response data object are in title case (i.e. pascal case), all that needs doing to each key is to make the first character lower case.

Below I've provided an a crude function (`mapPropNames`) which can do this mapping. Note that it works recursively so it will transform property names of all nested objects.

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const data = {
  "BudgetDays": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Date": "2019-01-08T00:00:00",
      "Earned": 10,
      "Spent": 8,
      "Logged": false,
      "LoggedTime": "2019-02-10T12:36:09.377"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Date": "2019-01-09T00:00:00",
      "Earned": 23,
      "Spent": 30,
      "Logged": false,
      "LoggedTime": "2019-02-10T12:36:09.38"
    },
 ],
};

function mapPropNames(o) {
  if (typeof o !== 'object' || o === null) {
    return o;
  }
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((a, key) => {
    // Customise the transformation of each property key if necessary
    const mappedKey = `${key[0].toLowerCase()}${key.slice(1)}`;
    a[mappedKey] = mapPropNames(o[key]);
    return a;
  }, o instanceof Array ? [] : {});
}

const request = of(data).pipe(
  map(mapPropNames),
);

request.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```